# Cutting a sphere along a curve

Tags: general-topology, surfaces

i have a question. I think that is not difficult, but i can't find a solution.7
I want to show the following:

**Cutting a sphere along a curve always results in two discs.**

Therefore i want to use the classification theorem and the Euler characteristic. Here my own ideas: Notice that we have a sphere, thus every curve seperates the surface and $\chi(F)=2$ (in addition these two facts are equivalent). But then, cutting along a curve must give:
$$2=\chi(F_1)+\chi(F_2)$$
But $\chi(F_i)\leq2$ because the Euler-characteristic is always lower of equal to $2$. But then we have two possbilities: $2=2+0$ or $2=1+1$. The first can not be true because every curve seperates the sphere. Thus it must be the second one. But then we may conclude that we have two discs.

**My Problem:** I don't know if i can make such a argumentation. I think i miss something, true?!

Thank you for help, hints and solutions.

Comment: Isn't this exactly Jordan curve theorem? a classical non-trivial result.

Comment: Your argument makes perfect sense by summation formula as stated by Damien.
But this only works when the curve is a **simple closed curve**. This condition will exclude all the weird behaviors including the case $2=0+2$ in you question.

Answer (score 1):

True, the Euler Characteristic is a homotopical measure, so $\chi ( \mathrm S^2) = \chi(\mathrm F_1) + \chi(\mathrm F_2) - \chi(\mathrm S^1)$ and as $\chi(\mathrm S^1) = 0$, you can find your conclusion !

Comment: Thank you but why does $\chi(S^2)=\chi(F_1)+\chi(F_2)−\chi(S^1)$ holds? is this not the fact we want to prove?

Comment: $\chi(\rm A \cup B) = \chi(A) + \chi(B) - \chi(A \cap B)$ is true for very general $\rm A$ and $\rm B$.

Comment: Oh yeah thanks :)

Comment: Is it true that $\chi(F)=1 \iff$ $F$ is a disc?

Comment: If by $\rm F$ you mean a topological manifold of dimension 1 with boundary $\rm S^1$ yes.